# Tracing recursion stack for the subset sum

Tags: algorithm, recursion, subset-sum

It all appears magical on how recursion can solve seemingly complex problems, I was reading [this](http://jeffe.cs.illinois.edu/teaching/algorithms/all-algorithms.pdf) paper which explains this algorithm beautifully. Here is my code in javascript:

```
function allButLast(arr) {
  return arr.slice(0, arr.length - 1);
}

function sSum(arr, sum) {
  //console.log(arr + ':' + sum);
  if (sum === 0) return true;
  if (sum < 0 || arr.length === 0) return false;

  return sSum(allButLast(arr), sum) || sSum(allButLast(arr), sum - arr.slice(-1));
}

/*
sSum([1, 2], 3)
sSum([1], 3) || sSum([1, 2], 1)
sSum([], 3) || sSum([], 2) || sSum([1, 2], 1)
false || sSum([], 2) || sSum([1, 2], 1)
false || false || sSum([1, 2], 1)
false || false || sSum([1], 1) || sSum([1], 1)
false || false || sSum([], 1) || sSum([], 0) || sSum([1], 1)
false || false || false || true || sSum([1], 1) // evaluation stops here
*/
//console.log(sSum([1, 2], 3));  // true
```

I wanted to understand and debug the function calls which I have documented in the comment, I want to know if that's how calls are executed and I am tracing it correctly?

Answer (score 1):

The first level sSym(1, 3) || sSum(1, 1) 
then sSym(1, 3) becomes sSym(, 3) || sSum(, 2) => False || False 
and sSum(1, 1) becomes sSym(, 1) || sSum(, 0) => False || true 
You can add
 `console.log('sSym(' + allButLast(arr) + ', '+ sum +') || sSum('+ allButLast(arr) + ', '+ (sum - arr.slice(-1)) +')')` 
before callin the return of sSum and this will help you in debugging